# AWS - Elasticbeanstalk - Issue in Role's policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-iam

Am trying to get health status of an application in ELB using the following CLI command.

```
aws elasticbeanstalk describe-environments --environment-nam my-env
```

It was working fine, when the resource policy was Policy A:

My application name: "QT"

**Policy A:**

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeEnvironments",
        "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeEnvironmenthealth"]
     }
 "Resource": ["*"],
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "elasticbeanstalk:InApplication": ["arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-east-2:123456789012:application/QT*"],
        }
        }
        ]
        }
```

**Policy B:**

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeEnvironments",
        "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeEnvironmenthealth"]
     }
 "Resource": ["arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-east-2:123456789012:application/QT"]
        ]
        }
```

**The problem is,**
When I use policy A it is working, but when I use policy B it is not working.
I cannot use policy A as it violates standards (wildcard usage in resource column)

Policy B stays compliant, but it returns empty list as result to the CLI command.

Any Help is highly appreciated.
TIA.

Answer (score 1):

In your second case, you are just providing ARN of application, not environment. The policy for the specific EB env would be:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeEnvironments",
        "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeEnvironmenthealth"],
     "Resource": ["arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-east-2:123456789012:application/QT/my-env"]
    }
    ]
}
```

Also your AWS CLI command is **incorrect**. It should be:

```
aws elasticbeanstalk describe-environments --environment-names my-env
```

Comment: I tried the same, but I can't retrieve results. am getting empty list as output for my "describe-environments" command from CLI with this policy.